# How embed a especifically Slide into Google Doc with Appscript like linked object?

Tags: google-apps-script, embedded-resource, google-slides

I need embed a slide into gdoc but like image linked, for example : https://i.stack.imgur.com/yldcn.png, ***using google appscrit***

my code is like this:

```
function addSlide() {
  var ppt = '11eQN3UdHYElUfCNp7Kpodgknqmw6ojuuwG18FbwOI0o'
  var preso = SlidesApp.openById(ppt);
  var s1 = preso.getSlides()[0];
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy_file.getId());
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.replaceText('{{TITULO}}', name);
  body.replaceText('{{SDA}}', sda);
  body.replaceText('{{OBJETIVO}}', objetivo);
  body.appendImage(s1.getLayout().getBackground().getPictureFill().getBlob());
}
```

but I dont know how linked slide image into doc ...

Comment: But the link would reference the image, not the Slide file. Is this correct?

Comment: I would like reference the Slide file, it is possible? for example , if you copy the slide and paste into document manually  its works. like there https://i.stack.imgur.com/yldcn.png , but I need  do it with Appscript.
the reason why must be linked, then  customer will modify it.